# Combining rows with same ID but different sequence number

Tags: python, mysql, terminal

I have a large (15m rows) csv file with multiple term periods (STRT_DTE and EXP_DATE) for some IDs. I also have a column called TRM_NBR that can take the values 1,2,3, etc. Sequential TRM_NBR's signify contiguous term periods (i.e., three rows with same ID and TRM_NBR 1,2,3 is one contiguous period whereas 1,2,1 is two periods).

I need to reduce the csv file so that I have one row per contiguous term period (and ID). See example below. Specifically, I need to output the ID, STRT_DTE from the **first term** in the sequence, and the EXP_DTE from the **last term** in the sequence. (Keeping TRM_NBR is optional.)

Original data:

```
ID;TRM_NBR;STRT_DTE;EXP_DTE
000020000007;1;2017-08-22 00:00:00.000;2016-09-20 00:00:00.000
000020000009;1;2015-07-23 00:00:00.000;2015-03-24 00:00:00.000
000020000017;1;2014-10-02 00:00:00.000;2014-10-02 00:00:00.000
000020000063;1;2018-11-19 00:00:00.000;2018-11-19 00:00:00.000
000020000063;2;2020-11-19 00:00:00.000;2020-11-19 00:00:00.000
000020000356;1;2020-06-23 00:00:00.000;2020-06-23 00:00:00.000
000020000356;2;2021-05-20 00:00:00.000;2021-05-20 00:00:00.000
000020000356;3;2022-04-21 00:00:00.000;2021-10-21 00:00:00.000
000020000356;2;2014-07-22 00:00:00.000;2014-09-09 00:00:00.000
000020000356;3;2015-07-21 00:00:00.000;2015-07-21 00:00:00.000
000020000356;4;2016-07-12 00:00:00.000;2016-07-12 00:00:00.000
000020000356;5;2017-07-11 00:00:00.000;2017-07-11 00:00:00.000
```

Desired output:

```
ID;TRM_NBR;STRT_DTE;EXP_DTE
000020000007;1;2017-08-22 00:00:00.000;2016-09-20 00:00:00.000
000020000009;1;2015-07-23 00:00:00.000;2015-03-24 00:00:00.000
000020000017;1;2014-10-02 00:00:00.000;2014-10-02 00:00:00.000
000020000063;1;2018-11-19 00:00:00.000;2020-11-19 00:00:00.000
000020000356;1;2020-06-23 00:00:00.000;2021-10-21 00:00:00.000
000020000356;2;2014-07-22 00:00:00.000;2017-07-11 00:00:00.000
```

Contiguous periods can be from 1 to infinity and **may or may not start with 1** but will always increment by 1 (if there are more than one row). Output file can contain multiple rows for same ID (but different sequences). You can assume that the file is ordered correctly in terms of sequence.

I can use Python, MySQL or Mac Terminal tools to solve.

Comment: *Contiguous periods can be from 1 to infinity and may or may not start with 1 but will always increment by 1 (if there are more than one row).* (1) Does the rows for one contiguous period are always contiguous and adjacent in your CSV? If there are TRM_NBR 1,2,3,4 for the same ID how can we define does this is one period or this is 2 periods which simply have no some another rows between them?

Comment: Contiguous rows are always adjacent. That's what I tried to express in the last sentence: "You can assume that the file is ordered correctly in terms of sequence." You can assume that if there are no repeated values (i.e., 1,1 or 2,2) then it is a sequence - i.e., 1,2,3,4 will always be a contiguous sequence.

Comment: I can give you a solution for MySQL. But you must define precise version of your MySQL server.

Comment: cheers. Version 8.0.25

Comment: Just one more point of clarification: I wrote "You can assume that if there are no repeated values (i.e., 1,1 or 2,2) then it is a sequence - i.e., 1,2,3,4 will always be a contiguous sequence." But as well as repeated values a new sequence could begin with decreasing values (i.e., 1,2,3,2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for MySQL.

1. Create a table for the source data importing into:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (
    rowno INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    id CHAR(12),
    trm_nbr TINYINT,
    strt_dte DATETIME(3),
    exp_dte DATETIME(3)
) ENGINE = Memory;
```

2. Import your source data into it:

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE 'X:/folder/filename.CSV'
INTO TABLE tmp
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(id, trm_nbr, strt_dte, exp_dte);
```

3. Process the data and save it to the output file:

```sql
WITH
cte1 AS ( SELECT *,
                 LAG(id) OVER (ORDER BY rowno) lag_id, 
                 1 + LAG(trm_nbr) OVER (ORDER BY rowno) lag_trm_nbr
          FROM tmp ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT *,
                 SUM(CASE WHEN (id, trm_nbr) = (lag_id, lag_trm_nbr)
                          THEN 0
                          ELSE 1 
                          END) OVER (ORDER BY rowno) grp_no
          FROM cte1 )
SELECT 'ID', 'TRM_NBR', 'STRT_DTE', 'EXP_DTE'
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(id) id, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MAX(id) ORDER BY grp_no) trm_nbr, 
       MIN(strt_dte) strt_dte, 
       MAX(exp_dte) exp_dte
FROM cte2
GROUP BY grp_no
INTO OUTFILE 'X:/folder/new_filename.CSV'
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f9760bc3271e8c0a7a20474c2dbae0ee)

---

Your current MySQL account must have FILE privilege.

`secure_file_priv` session variable value must be either empty string or some `drive:path` (check it by `SELECT @@secure_file_priv;` query). If it is not empty string then `X:/folder` in the queries must be equal to this value (on Windows system the backslashes in the path value must be doubled or replaced with direct slashes).

If `secure_file_priv` session variable value is NULL that you cannot use this method at all. In such case try to ask server administrator to set this variable and to allow the interaction with the filesystem.

The queries uses settings for Windows-style CSV, for Unix-style file use `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'`.

If your source file is too large (above ~100 Mbytes or above `max_allowed_packet` session variable value) then remove `ENGINE = Memory` from the table definition.

You do not need to delete temporary table - it will be deleted automatically when you close the connection. But you may drop it explicitly nevertheless.

Comment: Thanks. Just trying to figure out how to change secure_file_priv on local_db with MySQL Workbench...

Comment: I am unable to edit secure_file_priv but I do have access to another environment that runs version 5.7.3-38 (Percona Server). Would you be able to suggest a solution that works in this environment?

Comment: @MadsStenbjerre *I am unable to edit secure_file_priv* You must edit this parameter in my.ini and restart MySQL. *I do have access to another environment that runs version 5.7.3-38* My solution is not applicable to MySQL versions prior to 8.

Comment: No problem. I solved it by dropping the last bit (from "INTO OUTFILE...") and just saving the rows from the on-screen results. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Python alternative based on standard `itertools` and 3rd party [convtools](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools) library:

```py
import itertools

from convtools import conversion as c
from convtools.contrib.tables import Table

# read rows into iterable of dicts
rows = Table.from_csv(
    "input.csv", header=True, dialect=Table.csv_dialect(delimiter=";")
).into_iter_rows(dict)
# group into sequences of IDs
key_to_rows = itertools.groupby(rows, key=lambda r: r["ID"])

# prepare the converter, which takes groups of rows from the
# previous step and reduces each group to one row.
# This is where code generation happens, consider storing the
# resulting converter somewhere for further reuse.
converter = c.iter(
    c.item(1).pipe(
        c.aggregate(
            {
                "ID": c.ReduceFuncs.First(c.item("ID")),
                "LAST_TRM_NBR": c.ReduceFuncs.Last(c.item("TRM_NBR")),
                "STRT_DTE": c.ReduceFuncs.First(c.item("STRT_DTE")),
                "EXP_DTE": c.ReduceFuncs.Last(c.item("EXP_DTE")),
            }
        )
    )
).gen_converter()

# process iterable from itertools
processed_rows = converter(key_to_rows)

# output processed rows to "out.csv" (consider passing same dialect
# as above to .into_csv method
Table.from_rows(processed_rows).into_csv("out.csv")
```

The output is:

```
ID,LAST_TRM_NBR,STRT_DTE,EXP_DTE
000020000007,1,2017-08-22 00:00:00.000,2016-09-20 00:00:00.000
000020000009,1,2015-07-23 00:00:00.000,2015-03-24 00:00:00.000
000020000017,1,2014-10-02 00:00:00.000,2014-10-02 00:00:00.000
000020000063,2,2018-11-19 00:00:00.000,2020-11-19 00:00:00.000
000020000356,5,2020-06-23 00:00:00.000,2017-07-11 00:00:00.000
```